# Mulesoft - Load a JSON or XML properties file into a global variable

Tags: configuration, mule, anypoint-studio

I am trying to load a relatively simple configuration file into a variable that I can access globally within via MEL.  I don't want to use a typical properties field because my structure is not flat.

I was able to get somewhat close by loading the file as a bean as follows, but this left me with a giant string, rather than a hashmap (I can see why, I just didn't know how to fix it):

```
    <spring:bean id="ClientConfiguration" name="ClientConfiguration" class="java.lang.String" scope="singleton">
        <spring:constructor-arg>
            <spring:bean id="Test" name="org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils" class="org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils" factory-method="copyToByteArray">
                <spring:constructor-arg type="java.io.InputStream" value="classpath:client-configuration.json"/>
            </spring:bean>
        </spring:constructor-arg>
    </spring:bean>
```

Thoughts on appropriate or better ways to do this?

Comment: So you want to have an hashmap available in the context coming from an external file ?

Comment: Yes, essentially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution.

Class file:

```
package com.example;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.type.TypeReference;


public class JSONUtil {

    File in;
    public File getIn() {
        return in;
    }
    public void setIn(File in) {
        this.in = in;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getConfigAsMap(){        
        try{
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>> typeRef = new TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>>() {};

            Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue( in, typeRef);
            System.out.println(map);
            return map;
        } catch(Exception exception){
            exception.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Config:

```
    <spring:bean id="JSONUtil" class="com.example.JSONUtil" >
              <spring:property name="in"  value="classpath:client-configuration.json"/>
    </spring:bean>

    <spring:bean name="ClientConfiguration" factory-bean="JSONUtil" factory-method="getConfigAsMap" />
```

This is working and JSON Config is loaded as a Map.